# i need a complex sql query to get employee history

Tags: sql

I have one employee shift table which contains an employee id, shit and date.
actually i have daily inserting shifts for all employees. the table is looing like below one

```
Employee id       Shift      Date
----------------------------------
1                   G        2017-11-01 
1                   G        2017-11-02
1                  NG        2017-11-03
1                  NG        2017-11-04
1                   G        2017-11-05
1                   G        2017-11-06
1                   G        2017-11-07
1                   G        2017-11-08
```

I need output like below

```
Employee Id     Shift   From Date     To Date
1                 G     2017-11-01    2017-11-02
1                NG     2017-11-03    2017-11-04
1                 G     2017-11-05    2017-11-08
```

Thanks in advance. please help to write a easy login without using loops.

Comment: 1) Do not carpet bomb with every dbms tag under the sun.  2)  This is not how SO works.  You need to show some effort.  WHat have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a homework/code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Comment: Forgot DB2, Sybase, and of course, my perpetual favorite, dBase III.

Comment: @tadman: and obviously Postgres as well

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #merchant_comm(tid nvarchar(20), preval nvarchar(20), curval nvarchar(20), nextval nvarchar(20), datetimerequest datetime, nextdate datetime)

truncate table #merchant_comm

insert into #merchant_comm select * from (select tid,LAG(communication_mode) over (order by datetimerequest) preval, communication_mode curval, LEAD(communication_mode) over (order by datetimerequest) nextval,datetimerequest,LEAD(datetimerequest) over (order by datetimerequest) nextdate
from MRLPOSNET_MSCRM.dbo.Pos_RL_communication_mode_Merchant_Detail 
where tid = '3734200M') as a 
where preval <> nextval or nextval is null or preval is null  order by datetimerequest


  with CTE as (
  select tid,
case when preval is null then 1 when preval = curval then 0 when preval <> curval then 1 end as flag, 
curval as comm_mode, datetimerequest as from_date, lead(datetimerequest) over(order by datetimerequest) as to_date 
from #merchant_comm )


 select * from CTE where flag = 1
```